# AMDGPU-Pro Secondary Monitor currently in-op. What do?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, dvi

I have R9 380 Tonga chipset GPU, FX-8370 Piledriver chipset CPU and Ubuntu Mate freshly installed.  First thing I did was install AMDGPU-Pro.  Which it did, but I lost the functionality of my second screen. Its an older asus monintor vga w/dvi adaptors.

What rituals must I perform to make to the Ubuntu and/or AMD gods to get my second screen to work?

Comment: I asked the question on AMD forums too now.  Hopefully the AMD gods will be more generous than the Ubuntu gods.

Comment: Playing around with monitor preferences.  The display is being extended, but the second monitor is just not getting signal.  It is being detect though via terminal commands  let you see that sort of stuff and Steam detects two displays.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you have a sea island card which has trouble with the new amdgpu pro beta driver. I had the same problem with my r9 390. In order for it to work you need to compile and install a newer kernel with CIK enabled. Even then you wont be able to totally install the driver because the ubuntu version of the driver only installs the dkms module with the stock ubuntu kernel. To get the pro driver working i had to use a different distro. I installed arch linux with a custom kernel 4.8 and enabled CIK in the menuconfig. then i used yaourt to install the driver and also had to implement a patch so i could use any desktop environment that uses a compositor. I know its a pain but its the only way i found to get the card working completely. Also the open source driver with mesa 12.1 might not be a bad option as well. Unfortunately anyone with the types of gpu is in limbo waiting for kernel 4.9.....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)